# Comparator with hysteresis for bus-powered communication

Tags: comparator, bus, serial-bus

I have a circuit that, supposedly, converts a current-modulation signal to a digital signal. This is basically the receiver end of a bus-powered, bi-directional serial communication device (master).

There can be any number of slaves on the bus that normally draw up to 1.5mA each. Slave-to-master communication happens as a slave draws a variable current (I'm not quite sure about the details).

This is realised with a comparator in hysteresis configuration.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3rJwI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Without the capacitor `C` it's not hard to analyse, `V-` is always above `V+`, so `Vout`=0. This makes sense, as it's unknown how many slaves are drawing current the 'baseline' current `I` is unknown. (I use the abstraction that zero current goes into the comparator at `-` and `+`.)

Now, including the capacitor `C`, the intuition is, I think, that at higher frequencies the capacitor begins to short `V-` to ground, so at some point the comparator flips to `Vcc` as `V-` dips below `V+`.

And this is as far as I get. I'm not sure at all how to analyse this circuit and determine the values of the resistors and the capacitor. Is this whole setup even a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

The capacitor will attempt to hold the voltage at its top terminal at a constant DC voltage, removing higher-frequency signals.  It will not pull that terminal to ground.

It is often said that a capacitor appears as a short circuit to higher frequencies, but this does not mean that it becomes a DC short circuit in the presence of high frequencies.

Comment: Not to be a smock bastard, but its not often said :) It's a mathematical fact that the impedance of a capacitor which is frequency dependent by 1/jwc - so 1 over something infinitely large would be infinitely small.